# Bullet Prefab fire in the same direction the player is facing

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I am trying to have my bullet prefab fire in the same direction that my player is facing. Currently if the player faces north that's where the bullet fires, if the player faces south the bullet still fires north shooting straight through the player backwards.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class FireRocket : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject rocketPrefab;
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            GameObject rocketObject = Instantiate(rocketPrefab);
            rocketObject.transform.position = this.transform.position + transform.forward;
            
        }
    }
}
```

The bullet has a box collider and a rigidbody with the script attached. What else do i need to include so that I can have my bullet fire in the same direction my player is facing?

Rocket Script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Rocket: MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 15f;
    public float RocketLife = 10f;

    private float RocketLifeTimer;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        RocketLifeTimer = RocketLife;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        transform.position += transform.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime;

        RocketLife -= Time.deltaTime;
        if (RocketLifeTimer <= 0f)
        {
            Destroy(this.gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Rotate it correctly and set it's velocity accordingly? Please include your bullet script

Comment: Best practice would be to set the position and rotation in the ```Instantiate``` call, eg ```Instantiate(prefab, player.position, player.rotation);```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add transform.rotation = player rotation / or camera rotation

Comment: This and how do you expect bullet to fire player direction when you didn't add player rotation to code. From your code style, I can say you are beginner probably. I suggest you to watch some youtube videos or game course videos first. Then try to make yourself. Or learn programming throughly then try to code your game. Because it doesn't make sense making a **FireRocket** Class. Add bullet prefab to your player and when clicking left mouse button instantiate prefab and give rotation according to player facing direction.

Comment: @SeLeCtRa I assume you wanted to comment the original question and not add a comment to this answer. Anyhow, we all started coding as beginners and needed some help and guidance. Please be nice